# Is there a way to validate JavaScript objects with Laravel validation rules?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-10

I can't find any way to validate JS objects against Laravel's exact own validation rules. I have an object of data and an object of rules, I need to make sure the data fits all of the rules. The data is like this:

```js
{
    email: 'email@gmail.com',
    age: 24,
    name: 'john'
}
```

And the rules like this:

```js
{
   email: 'required|email',
   age: ['accepted', 'integer'] //or like this, it doesn't matter
}
```

I have a frontend and I don't want to make unnecessary requests and so error messages are instantaneous, but without the extra workload of adding in validation to everything individually

Answer (score 2):

I found this package

https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation

This is their introduction

> Laravel Javascript Validation package allows to reuse your Laravel
> Validation Rules, Messages, FormRequest and Validators to validate
> forms automatically in client side without need to write any
> Javascript code or use HTML Builder Class.
>
> You can validate forms automatically referencing it to your defined
> validations. The messages are loaded from your validations and
> translated according your Localization preferences.

Is it the thing you need?

Comment: No, sadly not. I think this is for Blade files that are connected, mine is a backend project and I just have two objects with the rules and data that I need to check match. But I will ask them if they can release the same thing but for two objects.